# Vue JS3 composition API with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am new to Vue JS3 and Firebase and need help with deleting documents from my firebase DB.
currently my code does execute any delete and the page doesn't even load.

I have created this composable to delete or edit a specific doc:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

const useDocument = (collection, id) => {
    const error = ref(null)
    const isPending = ref(false)

    let docRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

    const deleteDoc = async () => {
        isPending.value = true
        error.value = null
        try {
            const res = await docRef.delete()
            isPending.value = false
            return res
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err.message)
            isPending.value = false
            error.value = 'could not delete the document'
        }
    }

    return { error, isPending, deleteDoc }
}

export default useDocument
```

In the component I am importing this composable to delete the doc looks as so:

```
<script>
import useDocument from '../composables/useDocument'

export default {
    props:['id'],

    setup(props) {
        
        const { deleteDoc } = useDocument('orgaos', props.id)
        
        const router = useRouter()

        const handleDelete = async () => {
            await deleteDoc()
        }
        
        return { handleDelete }
    }
    
}
</script>
```

On the console I have the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.
    at new n (index.esm.js?c6c5:159:1)
    at us (index.esm.js?c6c5:13274:1)
    at n.doc (index.esm.js?c6c5:15719:1)
    at useDocument (useDocument.js?b80b:8:1)
    at setup (Orgaos.vue?051b:107:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:157:1)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js 5c40:7246:1)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:7201:1)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5524:1)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5499:1)
```

The Page code is as follows:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <NavbarAppHome />
        </div>
        <div>
            <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <div class="missao-list">
            <h2 class="dados_misso">LISTA DE ÓRGÃOS REGISTADOS</h2>
            <div class="table_missao">
                <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Órgãos</th>
                    <th scope="col">Departamento</th>
                    <th scope="col">SIGFE</th>
                    <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody v-if="documents">
                    <tr v-for="m in documents" :key="m.id">
                        <td>{{ m.nome_orgao }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.departamento_orgao }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.sigfe_orgao }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.sigfe_orgao }}</td>
                        <td><button title="Eliminar" class="icon_delete" @click="handleDelete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button><button title="Editar" class="icon_edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="error">{{ error2 }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

But as soon as I save the page just won't even show. Can someone please help me deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you call useDocument() with 1 arguments (collection orgaos) while you defined it to receive 2 (collection, id).
It should be `useDocument('orgaos', props.id)`

If the whole page is not showing, maybe fix that before trying anything else. What errors do you have in the console and what is the code of the page?

Comment: If the error shows when you click your delete button, it would be a problem about handleDelete(). But you said "as soon as I save the page just won't even show." so If your page doesn't even show at first, it is because it cannot get the documents from your database at the setup of your page

Comment: line 107 of your Orgaos.vue setup, as says your error (at setup (Orgaos.vue?051b:107:1))